# What is the point of op_Quotation if it cannot be used?

Tags: f#, operator-overloading

According the F# specification for [operator overloading](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fsharp/language-reference/operator-overloading)

```
<@ @>   op_Quotation
<@@ @@> op_QuotationUntyped
```

is given as with many other operators. Unless I'm missing something I don't believe that I can use this for custom types, so why is it listed?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you are right that there is no way of actually using those as custom operators. I suspect those are treated as operators in case this was useful, at some point in the future of the language, for some clever new feature.

The documentation really merely explains how the names of the operators get encoded. For non-special operator names, F# encodes those in a systematic way. For the ones listed in the page, it has a special nicer name. Consider this type:

```
type X() = 
  static member (<^><>) (a:int,b:int) = a + b
  static member (<@ @>) (a:int,b:int) = a + b
```

If you look at the names of those members:

```
[ for m in typeof<X>.GetMembers() -> m.Name ]
```

You see that the first operator got compiled as `op_LessHatGreaterLessGreater`, while the second one as `op_Quotation`. So this is where the name memntioned in the table comes in - it is probably good this is documented somewhere, but I think you're right, that this is not particularly useful!